# Segmentation fault using vectors in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I am searching for a segmentation fault I have programmed into my code. It basically appears, when my function `parseRecord(string)` generates a vector and if I want to print out one of the elements. I have narrowed it down to that point, but can't find the error. The vectors are Record objects, which are created by reading a file, which has one row of data each line.

Whenever I create a Object of the class (without creating a vector) I can print the element just fine. It only appears whenever I use the parseRecord(string) function which is creating the vector.

I also tried to print it in the function itself with the same result. So I think it isn't a scope problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

#include "record.hpp"

ifstream parsefile(string filename);
std::vector<Record> parseRecord(string line);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::vector<Record> dataSet = parseRecord("data.dat");

    Record record("D11101001", "Max", "Muestermann",
                  10239, "fictionalmarkt.com", "23.12.19", "11:11:00");

    cout << record;

    for(std::vector<Record>::const_iterator i = dataSet.begin(); i != dataSet.end(); ++i){
        cout << *i << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

//METHOD-IMPLEMENTATION
//parse-file definition - Test if file is accessible
ifstream parsefile(string filename)
{
    ifstream inFile(filename);
    if (!inFile)
    {
        cerr << "File could not be opened" << endl;
        exit(-1);
    }
    cout << "Input-file is readable!" << endl;
    return inFile;
}

//parse-record definition - read file, add to vector<Record> and return vector
std::vector<Record> parseRecord(string filename)
{
    vector<Record> dataSet;

    ifstream inFile = parsefile(filename);
    string line;

    while (getline(inFile, line))
    {
        stringstream linestream(line);
        string accountNb;
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        string amountStr; //format 100 = 1.00€
        string merchant;
        string date;
        string time;
        long double amount;

        getline(linestream, accountNb, '|');
        getline(linestream, firstName, '|');
        getline(linestream, lastName, '|');
        getline(linestream, amountStr, '|');
        getline(linestream, merchant, '|');
        getline(linestream, date, '|');
        getline(linestream, time, '\n');

        try
        {
            amount = stold(amountStr);
        }
        catch (const std::exception &e)
        {
            std::cerr << e.what() << '\n'
                      << "Conversion error";
        }

        amount *= 100.0; //to correct the decimal format

        Record recordEntry(accountNb, firstName, lastName, amount, merchant, date, time);

        //cout << recordEntry << endl;

        dataSet.push_back(recordEntry);
    }

    return dataSet;
}
```

record.hpp

```cpp
class Record
{
private:
    string accountNb;
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    long double amount; //format 100 = 1.00€
    string merchant;
    string date;
    string time;
public:
    Record(string, string, string, long double, string, string, string);
    ~Record();
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Record&);
};
```

record.cpp

```cpp
#include "record.hpp"
#include <ostream>

Record::Record(string accountNb, string firstName, string lastName,
               long double amount, string merchant, string date, string time)
{
    this->accountNb = accountNb;
    this->firstName = firstName;
    this->lastName = lastName;
    this->amount = amount;
    this->merchant = merchant;
    this->date = date;
    this->time = time;
}

Record::~Record()
{
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Record &rec)
{
    os << right;
    os << setw(15) << "Account Nb:" << setw(50) << rec.getAccountNb() << endl;
    os << setw(15) << "First Name:" << setw(50) << rec.getFirstName() << endl;
    os << setw(15) << "Last Name:" << setw(50) << rec.getLastName() << endl;
    try
    {
        os << showbase;
        os << setw(15) << "Amount:" << setw(50);
        os.imbue(std::locale("de_DE.UTF-8"));
        os << put_money(rec.getAmount(), true) << endl;
    }
    catch (const std::exception &e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << "locale not supported system";
    }
    os << setw(15) << "Merchant:" << setw(50) << rec.getMerchant() << endl;
    os << setw(15) << "Date:" << setw(50) << rec.getDate() << endl;
    os << setw(15) << "Time:" << setw(50) << rec.getTime() << endl;
}
```

As result the console prints:

```
Account Nb:                                         D11101001
First Name:                                               Max
 Last Name:                                       Muestermann
    Amount:                                       102,39 EUR
First Name:                                             Jonny
 Last Name:                                               Doe
    Amount:                                        80,38 EUR
  Merchant:                                          markt.de
      Date:                                          25.12.19
      Time:                                         11:11:19
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

So it quits after the first row.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mre] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Are you sure that `dataSet` has size >= 2 when you print it in `main`?

Comment: Why are you doing `cout <<  dataSet[1]` in the for loop?

Comment: This `cout <<  dataSet[1] << *i << endl;` inside your main seems fishy, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: I wanted to test, whether it works. I will clean it up. Sorry for that.

Comment: Does it still crash with it removed?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, it still crashes.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yes the data.dat file has 3 Line with entries.

Comment: `Segmentation fault using vectors in C++?` -- Replace the usage of `[ ]` with `at()`.  I bet you no longer get the segmentation fault, but an actual exception thrown (`std::out_of_range`).  Also, your exception handling for an invalid double is faulty -- your code continues on as if there is nothing wrong.

Comment: Maybe the bug is in operator<<( ) or something in `Record`

Comment: Then we need a [mre]

Comment: @drescherjm I will post the definition of the operator<<() in the post in a second

Comment: Have you stepped through code with a debugger?

Comment: `amount *= 100.0; //to correct the decimal format` -- Since `amount` is uninitialized, this could do all sorts of weird stuff, including crash, if the exception before that line was thrown.

Comment: `ostream &operator<<` -- You really should heed the warnings your compiler is giving you.  You are not returning a value here, thus the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One error is that you are not returning a value from this function:

`ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Record &rec)`

Not returning a value from a function declared to return a value is undefined behavior.

```
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Record &rec)
{
    //...
    return os; // <-- you are missing this line
}
```

---

The above is the obvious error, but another potential error is within your test for a valid `double`.  You catch an exception, but then your code goes on as if the `double` is valid, when it is actually uninitialized.

```
double amount;  // <--uninitialized.
//..
try
{
   amount = stold(amountStr);
}
catch (const std::exception &e)
{
   std::cerr << e.what() << '\n' << "Conversion error";
}

amount *= 100.0; // <-- behavior undefined if exception above this line was thrown.
```

Comment: Thank you so much! It works! It is really strange, that it worked with a directly created object. Only after adding -Wall to my gcc-compiler the warning was visible.
Lesson learned. My IDE didn't show me anything either.
Thank you all for your help! I think I would have spent another 3 hours without any result :/

Comment: @THE-E It "worked" with directly created object because you didn't chain `<<` calls. In the loop you have `cout << *it` which returns some rubbish, and then, the result of this expression is chained with next operator `<< endl` - it means you do `[some rubbish] << endl;`. In general, *UB is not reasonable at all*, but that's the most probable explanation.